# PHP MariaDB while loop runs when there are no rows

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Running a Lamp stack and now with MariaDB instead of MySQL.
I run a select query  but if nothing is returned I get an infinite error loop, locks up my DB server and floods the error log.

Here is the code below. 
When using MYSQL no problem.
So now I am checking for the number of rows in the result before hand and then bypassing the while loop.

What am I missing? I don't want to have to refactor all my code.

```
$sql="select  COUNT(DISTINCT garmtypeid) as stylecount,garmtypeid as styleid,
       count(objects.id) as itemqty,objectstyles.code,objectstyles.description,
        objectstyles.bundleqty,sum(objectstyles.forbiddenitem) as forbiddenitem,
       objectstyles.altdescription
    from  objects
    left join  objectstyles on objectstyles.id = objects.garmtypeid
    where  rfid in ($Taglist2)
    group by  garmtypeid ";
error_log("BUNDLLLE");
error_log($sql);

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

 while (($rowx =mysql_fetch_assoc($result))!==false)
{....}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `$rowx =mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` is an assignment which does not strictly equate to `false`, therefore creating your infinite loop. It may however with a loose comparison (`!=` instead of `!==`). In fact, since `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns a non-empty array on success and `false` on failure you don't even need the comparison at all.

See the documentation on [type comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for a full reference.

Answer (score 0):

(Other issues)

```
COUNT(DISTINCT garmtypeid) as stylecount
...
group by  garmtypeid
```

-->

```
COUNT(*) as stylecount
...
group by  garmtypeid
```

Do you need `LEFT`?

Do *not* use the `mysql_*` interface; switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.